# Prove the following inequality using ${AM \geq GM}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that ${(n!)^2>n^n}$.

I am trying to use the ${AM \geq GM}$ inequality but I am not getting what I should get. Please help!
Thank you!! :))

Comment: I guess $$n!<n^n$$

Comment: are you mad ??? this is totally wrong question...see for n=3..

Comment: yaa @ user142634

Comment: i guess it is (n!)^2

Comment: as for (n!)^2>n^n @ abir mukherjee

Comment: Sorry for the typo!! I have edited the question! :))

Answer (score 2):

$$(n!)^2=n1\ (n-1)2\ (n-2)3\cdots 2(n-1)\ 1n > n^n$$
because for $1\le k\le n-1$ each factor $(n-k)(k+1)=(n-k-1)k+n>n$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the induction:

- For $n=1$ the result is clear.
- The inductive step
  $$(n+1)!=(n+1)n!\le (n+1)n^n\le (n+1)(n+1)^n=(n+1)^{n+1}$$
  so
  $$n!\le n^n,\qquad \forall n\ge1$$